# Compare between different categories across specific column

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to compare between different categories across specific columnn

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> A = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], "col2":['x','y','x1','y']})
A
col1  col2
A      x
A      y
B      x1
B      y
```

So can we compare between categories in col1 (A and B) across col2. If you see, A has x and y values. But B has x1 and y values.
Can we write a code to tell to compare these values and get x1 as output since it is not present in A. Similarly get x as output since it is not present in B.

Just a pivot between A and B values across col2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which output you expect, but you could use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) operations to get a global output:

```
sets = A.groupby('col1')['col2'].agg(set)

S = set(A['col2'])

missing = S-S.intersection(*sets)
```

Output: `{'x', 'x1'}`

Or per value in "col1":

```
S = set(A['col2'])
out = A.groupby('col1')['col2'].agg(S.difference)
```

Output:

```
col1
A    {x1}
B     {x}
Name: col2, dtype: object
```

Or with you original idea of a `pivot`, but with the more convenient [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html), a [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) and [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
tmp = pd.crosstab(A['col1'], A['col2'])

out = tmp.where(tmp.eq(0)).stack().index
```

Output:

```
MultiIndex([('A', 'x1'),
            ('B',  'x')],
           names=['col1', 'col2'])
```

With lists as output:

```
out = tmp.where(tmp.eq(0)).stack().reset_index().groupby('col1')['col2'].agg(list)
```

Output:

```
col1
A    [x1]
B     [x]
Name: col2, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to compare between different categories across a specific column in Pandas. One way to accomplish this is by using the pivot_table() function in Pandas. Here's an example of how you can use pivot_table() to compare the values in col2 across the different categories in col1:

```
import pandas as pd

# create the DataFrame
A = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], "col2":['x','y','x1','y']})

# pivot the DataFrame on col1 and col2
pivot = pd.pivot_table(A, index='col1', columns='col2', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)

# compare the values in col2 across the different categories in col1
diff = pivot.diff(axis=0).fillna(pivot)

# get the values that are present in B but not in A
b_not_a = diff.loc['B'][diff.loc['A'] == 0].index.tolist()

# get the values that are present in A but not in B
a_not_b = diff.loc['A'][diff.loc['B'] == 0].index.tolist()

print("Values present in B but not in A:", b_not_a)
print("Values present in A but not in B:", a_not_b)
```

In this example, we first create the DataFrame A. We then use pivot_table() to pivot the DataFrame on col1 and col2. The resulting pivot table shows the count of occurrences of each value in col2 for each category in col1. We then use diff() to compute the difference between the counts for categories A and B. The resulting DataFrame diff shows the values that are present in B but not in A, and the values that are present in A but not in B. Finally, we use tolist() to convert the index of diff to a list and print the results.

Comment: Have you used AI to generate this answer?

Comment: @takao, I get wrong answer ````Values present in B but not in A: ['x1']
Values present in A but not in B: ['y']```` . Values present in A but not in B should be x right?